# How to remove words using grep in other languages?

Tags: r, regex

I try to remove strings from a dataframe using `grep` for Greek language.

```
df <- data.frame(freetext = c("Εδώ και αρκετό καιρό που συνεχίζουν","και τώρα που έγιναν"))

df <- df_text[!grepl("και|που", df),]
```

And the error is

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, text, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 2
```

Is there any issue with language?

Expected data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(freetext = c("Εδώ αρκετό καιρό συνεχίζουν","τώρα έγιναν"))
```

Comment: Either `df_text` is missing from your question or it is supposed to be `df` in which case I actually do not get an error.

Comment: Instead of `df_text[!grepl(...)]`, if you want to invert the sense of the grep, i.e. find all non-matching lines, use `grep(..., invert=T)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no issues with the language, but there are several others. You want

```
df$freetext <- gsub("(και|που)[$ ]", "", df$freetext)
df
#                      freetext
# 1 Εδώ αρκετό καιρό συνεχίζουν
# 2                 τώρα έγιναν
```

`grepl` is used only to detect certain patterns, not to do any changes. For that you want `gsub`. Then also you are dealing with a vector `df$freetext`, not a whole data frame `df`, and the assignment has to be to the same column, not the whole data frame. Lastly, the pattern needs `[$ ]` meaning the end of the character or a space as not to erase και form καιρό.

Comment: even if I use `df_text2 <- !grepl("και|που", df_text)` the result is not a dataframe as we expect.

Comment: @foc, please add your expected output to the question.